# importing numpy in different python versions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem with importing numpy for python3, I'm new in coding and followed all steps.  I want to import numpy in python3 but not in python2 which is set by defaultn my mac mojave 10.14.2.

I have Python 2.7.10 by default on my mac and can switch now to Python 3.7.2 in shell. I installed pip 18.1 as described in PyPA and now I can import numpy only in Python 2. what should I do to be able to import numpy in Python 3? Is it better to set Python 3 by default on my mac mojave 10.14.2?

Comment: You probably want to read up on what virtualenvs are.

Answer (score 3):

You can install `numpy` in python3 with help of `pip3` command instead of pip.
Yes you should change python3 as default as python2 support is going to end this year.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about Python environments. This will allows you to works with specific Python version and dependences separeted by project. Now days it is almost a must for all Pythonysts.

https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Answer (score 0):

pip is for python 2, pip3 is for python 3

Start by updating the package list using the following command:

```
sudo apt update
```

Use the following command to install pip for Python 3:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Once the installation is complete, verify the installation by checking the pip version:

```
pip3 --version
```

Then install numpy using pip3

```
pip3 install numpy
```